# Mnemonic for spelling 'anonymous'?

Tags: mnemonic

I have difficulties spelling anonymous because I have trouble remembering how to even say it. Is there an easy way to remember its spelling?

Comment: anon - y - mou(se)

Comment: Practice makes perfect. Write it down a hundred times, then type it a hundred times. No really, go ahead and do just that. That is how you learn the spelling of *all* words, after all. Ideally, you should also read it a hundred times. (Which in this day and age is easier than ever, as you can simply search the Web or a corpus, and get any number of sentences using it in context.)

Comment: A NO Named Yutz Might Over Use Symbols

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Anonymous: **A** nyone  **N** ot  **O** penly  **N** amed.  **Y** et  **M** ore  **O** ften:  **U** nknown  **S** ource.

Does that fit the bill?

Answer (score 4):

Associate these not too precise fragments:

Greek -> Latin:
onyma = bear a name
onymus = a work/entity that bears a name.
an onymus = unnamed.

From which English derives:
onymous = an entity that bears a name; a work whose author or creator is named

syn onymous = same named
al onymous = having asummed alternate name
an onymous = un named

Hence,
syn-onym, syn-onymous-ly
al-onym, al-onymous-ly
an-onymous-ly

Comment: Wow thanks! Although not a mnemonic, it really helped! I didn't realize the there are other words with `onymus` at the end.

Comment: See also antonym, acronym, pseudonym, homonym, eponymous

Answer (score -1):

For writing it:

- Write it on an index card and refer to it when you need it.
- use a spell checker. They are actually quite good these days.

For saying it:

If you cannot remember how to say it, avoid using it.

If you want to use the word, but can't remember how to say it, do what we all do: put in some work and practice!

Say in private. "Ahh - non - ee - mus"

There now. Four syllables.